# Visual Studio, cshtml file, understanding how arabic characters are treated

Tags: visual-studio, razor, fonts, arabic

Take the character "ب". It shows in stack overflow. I can see this in a cshtml file and in a js file

The character "ُ" on the other hand shows here correctly. However it shows as a question mark in the cshtml file and js file. If I copy it to notepad it shows as a Ḍammah (a loop normally above a letter which indicates a 'u' sound)

Why is it a question mark in the cshtml file if notepad understands it? ALso Visual Studio understands other arabic characters so why not this one

All I can think of is that a Dammah (as far as I know) always sits above another letter so can't be used in isolation?

What I'm trying to do is detect words that have a Dammah in them via Javascript

I'm completely new to unicode and non acii characters so this may be a stupid question, apologies if so

Comment: `question mark` means a missing glyph here. so try a better and complete font.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So Visual Studio uses a worse font to Notepad? This is on Windows 8.

Comment: You're right. Weirdly both Visual Studio and notepad use Consolas, still when I change to Courier New I can see the characters. If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It often happens that an application uses a default font that does not support all the unicode characters that a usecase requires. In such a case, try to change the font to a more compatible one. "Courier New" works mostly well, also "Arial Unicode MS" does a good job. But there is no font that covers totally everything, so maybe you will need to switch between two or three fonts to cover all required characters. For Arabic, "Arial" is a good choice, but there are many interesting alternatives.